# Find all integer solutions, $(ax-b)^2+(bx-a)^2=x$

Tags: integers

Find all $(,,) \in \mathbb{z}^3$ satisfying

$(−)^2+(−)^2=$.

I found $(0,0,0)$
and $(±1,±1,2)$.

And for the case $≠$
, the $\Delta$ of quadratic in $x$ is
$$(4+1)^2−(2^2+2^2)^2=^2$$
we set $\Delta=^2$ so that $x$ may be an integer.

Equaling the general formula for pythagorean triples $(^2+^2,2,^2−^2)$
and after some confusing steps of substitutions involving $$, $$ and $$ found that
$$2(+)^2+1=0$$

which implies no solutions.

But I'm afraid that my solution is wrong because I've never seen Pythagorean triples used like that.

Can someone give another solution maybe more clarifying?

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the work leading to the conclusion that $$a = b \implies 2(a+b)^2 + 1 = 0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computation is correct for the discriminant, then you can observe that:
$$k^2 = (4ab+1+2a^2+2b^2)(4ab+1-2a^2-2b^2) = \left(2(a+b)^2+1\right)\left(1-2(a-b)^2\right) < 0$$
if $a\neq b.$ This forces $a = b$ in particular. Your method of using the general formula for Pythagorean triplets is correct but also an overkill.

Comment: Wow, I totally overkilled it. Thanks!